# how to search data from datatable using textbox and display it into datagridview in C#?

Tags: c#, search, datagridview, datatable

i want to search data from datatable using a textbox, and display it into datagridview (datatable is the datasource for datagridview). 
I tried using this code:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(@"C:\ABC.xml");

        table.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Name"), new DataColumn("Id"), new DataColumn("MobileNo.") });
        XmlNodeList path = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Data");
        foreach (XmlNode node in path)
            {
                String name= node.Attributes["name"].Value;
                String id= node.Attributes["id"].Value;
                String number= node.Attributes["no."].Value;


                table.Rows.Add(name, id, number);

                BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
                bindingSource.DataSource = table;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;    
            }
     }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = new DataView();
        dv.RowFilter = "Name like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
    }
```

Here I am taking data from an xml, storing it in a datatable and using this as data source for datagridview.

I want to provide a search option for the "Name" using a textbox. 
The above code is not working as desired, only the data is displayed in the grid , but unable to search for text entered in textbox. 
Kindly help with any other solution you have.

Comment: The missing space in Namelike can't be the problem?

Comment: Change "dv.RowFilter = "Namelike '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";" to "dv.RowFilter = "Name like '%" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%'";"

Comment: Sorry that was by mistake.. even giving space is resulting into the same

Comment: @kumarch1: No, it is not working that way also. And when i click on search button, it says that the id column already exists.

Comment: Add dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;dataGridView1.DataBind();  inside textBox1_TextChanged method

Comment: Is there any reference to be attached for this?? as its showing no definition for "dataGridView1.DataBind();"

Comment: is it a windows or web app? if windows app you don't need that line. And one more thing where is the data for your dataview. I don't see any datasource for the dataview !

Comment: @kumarch1: yes that was only missing. Added the datasource for data view. Thanx alot!

Answer (score 0):

got it!

the datasource for dataview was missing.

corrected function:

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv = new DataView(table);
    dv.RowFilter = "Name like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
}
```